# Google Script Long Function in If Else Statement

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So I managed to figure out how to control the styling within a tableCell:

```
AllCellA1.clear().insertParagraph(0,m2).setSpacingAfter(0).setSpacingBefore(0).setLineSpacing(1);
```

But that involves me having to make a very large table with stacked functions:

```
var ChangeAllCells = file.appendTable();
var AllRow1 = ChangeAllCells.appendTableRow();
var AllCellA1 = AllRow1.appendTableCell();
var AllCellB1 = AllRow1.appendTableCell();
var AllRow2 = ChangeAllCells.appendTableRow();
var AllCellA2 = AllRow2.appendTableCell();
var AllCellB2 = AllRow2.appendTableCell();
```

The problem is that I'm trying to run if else statements and this table just isn't working! The script doesn't run WITHIN the if else statement (too long, not correct syntax?) and if it's before or after, the script runs outside of the if else statement.

```
if(m1 == ""){
    file.insertParagraph(0, "END OF REPORT");
  }else if(m1 || ""){
    if(m10 || ""){
      file.insertParagraph(0, m1);
      ChangeAllCells;
    }else if(m9 || ""){
      file.insertParagraph(0, m1); 
      **ABOVE SCRIPT GOES HERE*;
    }
```

Is there some kind of work around for this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

`||` is the symbol for `or`.  Saying `else if(m1 || "")` doesn't make sense.  you would have to say something like `else if(m1 == "a" || m1 == "b")`